# Custom CSS file present in head but fails to load

Tags: css, magento2.3.4

I have a custom theme that inherits from Magento/blank.
I want to add a custom `.css` file to this theme. To do so, I've followed the Magento documentation that explains the steps: [Include CSS](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-themes.html#fedg_css-in-themes_xml)

> **Note** that my Magento instance is in a `developer` mode

In my current state, the filesystem path to my custom css file is:

```
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<my-theme>/web/css/custom-style.css
```

I've created the `default_head_blocks.xml` file at:

```
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<my-theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

With the following content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <head>
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <css src="css/custom-style.css" src_type="url" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
</page>
```

> Nothing more here than what the docs says to do

Adding the `<css>` node to the `.xml` file **is working properly**: there is a `<link>` node in the resulting source code of my page

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom-style.css" />
```

**My issue is** that the loading of this file fails with a "(canceled)" Status when checking it in the Chrome Network tab:

[image: Chrome Network Tab error]

**Note how the path of my custom file is different than the one for other successfully loaded files.**

My file is looked up at

```
/css/custom-style.css
```

whereas the standard theme files are looked up at

```
/pub/static/versionXYZ/frontend/<Vendor>/<my-theme>/en_US/css/<file-name>
```

I would suppose that this explains why the loading fails (accessing this path directly with the browser yields a 404 Not Found).

**What I tried**

- Removing `pub/static/*` content (keeping the `.htaccess` file, of course)
- Removing `var/view_preprocessed/*` content
- Cleaning the cache with `cache:clean`, and flushing it with `cache:flush`
- Running the Grunt `exec:<my-theme>` task along with the `less:<my-theme>` task

> I **did not** run `setup:static-content:deploy` and I shouldn't have to, since I'm in `developer` mode

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can I help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code  replace `default_head_blocks.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/custom-style.css" /> 
    </head>
</page>
```

and after that please please run below commands

```
php bin/magento c:c

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Awesome! That worked really well! The culprit was the `src_type="url"` property. Removing just this property made the CSS load properly. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: welcome bro please accept answer too if useful